# React 16 - ES6 - Webpack - Error: Module is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, react-hot-loader

I have a react app written in ES6 code.

I get this error after upgrading my react version (15.4.2 -> 16.4.0), along with react-hot-loader (1.3.1 -> 4.3.0).

This is my `package.json` before:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.7",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    ...
}
```

This is my `package.json` after:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.0",
    ...
}
```

My webpack version is set to : `"webpack": "^3.11.0"`.

My webpack config is set to:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      ...
    ],
},
```

After I refreash my app, I get the following error message:

> Error: Module '...\node_modules\react-hot-loader\index.js' is not a loader (must have normal or pitch function)

How can I get react-hot-loader to work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TL;DR:**
>
> Remove `react-hot-loader` from any loaders in your Webpack config, and add `react-hot-loader/babel` to the plugins section of your `.babelrc` instead.

**More thorough explanation:**

As the docs in `react-hot-loader` v4.3.1 [state](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#getting-started),

Add `react-hot-loader/babel` to your `.babelrc`:

```
// .babelrc
{
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

> Note: Put the `react-hot-loader/babel` plugin to the most left of the plugins list above.

Update your Webpack config to not use the `react-hot-loader` plugins since Babel will do that for you:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader'],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      ...
    ],
},
```